# List element in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, list, components, element

I make a list element in React but I don't understand why it does not appear. Do I have to do a class component?

**List.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';


const styles = {
  root: {
      display: 'flex',
      backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
      width: '100%',
  },
}

function ListSeances(props) {

    const { classes } = props;

    const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    const listItems = list.map((item) =>{
        <li>{ item }</li>
    });


      return (
         <div className={classes.root}>
           <ul>{ listItems }</ul>
         </div>
      )
  }

export default withStyles (styles)(ListSeances);
```

**MapAppBar**

```
class MapAppBar extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const { classes, animation } = this.props

    return(
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <App_Bar className={classes.appBar} position="fixed">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
        </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
      <TextFields/>
        <DatePicker/>
        <DatePicker2/>
      <ListSeances/>
    </App_Bar>
  </div>
  )
  }
}
```

My list is supposed to appear in `MapAppBar.js`. I put the `import ListSeances from './List';` in.

Answer (score 0):

You do not return anything in the map function. In your case, you map every value to `undefined`, because you have written a **block statement**.

try (no curly braces, the `(` and `)` are not necessary, too):

```
const listItems = list.map((item) => (
    <li>{ item }</li>
));
```

or (properly with a return statement)

```
const listItems = list.map((item) => {
    return <li>{ item }</li>
});
```

it is because of the curly braces. 
I think a really good way of describing, how arrow functions work, was written by Marius Schulz.

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/06/09/returning-object-literals-from-arrow-functions-in-javascript

in your case, the mapping function when using arrow function could be written

```
const mapper = item => (<li>{ item }</li>)
```

or, if you do not return an object literal

```
const mapper = item => {
    return <li>{ item }</li>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and the articles. It works and i understood why.